# Where should I put styled-components with CRA?

Tags: reactjs

I created my project with create-react-app(Typescript template).
Src folder

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 danilov danilov  506 феб 17 13:08 App.tsx
-rw-rw-r-- 1 danilov danilov  453 феб 17 12:51 index.css
-rw-rw-r-- 1 danilov danilov  500 феб 17 11:35 index.tsx
-rw-rw-r-- 1 danilov danilov   40 феб 17 11:35 react-app-env.d.ts
-rw-rw-r-- 1 danilov danilov  425 феб 17 11:35 reportWebVitals.ts
-rw-rw-r-- 1 danilov danilov  241 феб 17 11:35 setupTests.ts
```

Where should I place styled components? In index.css after the html,body and code sections?

Comment: It is a bit of an open question, but I suggest creating a structure in the `./src` folder; `components`, `pages/screens`, `services`, ..etc Your Styled components can then live in the components folder in their own folder. e.g. `./src/components/Header/Header.tsx`

Comment: What do you mean where to place them? You write its logic in the component's file

Comment: @Christiaan Then I should point to index.css,right?

Comment: Are we talking about the same [Styled Components](https://styled-components.com/)?

Comment: @Christiaan Yes,exactly the same.

Comment: Ok, the index.css file is only used as an example in the boilerplate. You could define some styling for your application, but your Styled Components don't need the index.css file at all.

Comment: @Christiaan ok. thanks, they made confusion with this index.css.